# ă ş ţ chars aren't rendered by iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I use iTextSharp in asp.net mvc to return pdf like this:

```
public class Pdf : IPdf
    {
        public FileStreamResult Make(string s)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var document = new Document())
                {
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
                    document.Open();
                    using (var str = new StringReader(s))
                    {
                        var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);

                        htmlWorker.Parse(str);
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyPdfName.pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                return new FileStreamResult(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that characters like: `ă ţ ş` are not rendered

Comment: did you tried using the hexadecimal value? did you tried for the encoding to support such characters? I use `Æ` `Ø` and `Å` very well with iTextSharp.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322303/html-to-pdf-some-characters-are-missing-itextsharp

Comment: This is not an answer, but an observation regarding the code above (not related to your question but it might help you in the future): the ms.GetBuffer() can generate damaged PDF file in some situations, you can read here more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109384/itextsharp-generated-pdfs-now-cause-save-dialog-in-adobe-reader-x

Comment: @balexandre your chars work for me too, how would I use the hexadecimal value ?

Comment: did you tried change the encoding as I said? `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = "ISO-8859-16";` --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16

Comment: @balexandre tried this `CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ro-RO");
            Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(ci.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);
            Response.ContentEncoding = enc;` doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

yetanothercoder is correct.  That would do the trick... but there's another very similar question which I answered in a bit more detail:

[iText + HTMLWorker - How to change default font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935308/itext-htmlworker-how-to-change-default-font/4937419#4937419)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the folowing:

```
var unicodeFont = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CP1250, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
acroFields.SetFieldProperty("txtContractorBirthPlace", "textfont", unicodeFont, null);
```

And it should do it for you.
You have to add the field property to every field you wish to have diacritics.

**Baftă!**