# HTML to PDF Conversion of Arabic Text from Itext 5.5 and XMLWorker

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I am trying to convert an HTML String with arabic Text from Itext 5.5 & XMLWorker.
After conversion, Arabic Characters are displayed blank.

The Code Snippet used is as follows:

```
public class CreateArabic {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(8.5f * 72, 11 * 72);

            Document document = new Document(pagesize, 72, 72, 72, 72);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("c:\\report.pdf"));

            writer.getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true);

            document.open();

            FontFactory.registerDirectories();
            Font font = FontFactory.getFont("C:\\damase.ttf",
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, 22, Font.BOLD);


            document.open();



             XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
             // CSS
             CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
             CssFile cssFile = helper.getCSS(new FileInputStream(
             "D:\\Itext_Test\\Test\\src\\test.css"));
             cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

             // HTML
             XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
             fontProvider.getFont("C:\\damase.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
             fontProvider.register("C:\\damase.ttf");


             CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
             HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(
             cssAppliers);
             htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

             PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
             HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
             CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
             html);

             XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);

             XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

                         String htmlString = "<html><head></head><body>"+"اب"+"</body></html>";

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

p.parse(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));



             document.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your code it's not added properly.

Comment: What is the issue? Please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue, just difference is that i have used Turkish font and that are missing:-

please see my answer [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397331/itextsharp-html-to-pdf-some-turkish-characters-are-missing/21746699#21746699) for this

Hope helps you
Regards,