# content from html missing in pdf created by iTextrenderer

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I am trying to create pdf from one html which has chinese char.
in this i have got weird prob.
the line from html which has chinese char is not completely shown in pdf generated from it.

Below is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1?DTD/transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>some title.</title>

<style type="text/css">
     .name
   {
         font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
         color:red;
         margin-left: 5px;
         margin-right: 5px
     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <b class="name">

LLTRN,DEBIT,,,6841,FXW,,CNY,PAY,C,,,,DD,,ord par nm,,,,,,,CN,百威英博雪津(三明)啤酒有限公司,,,,,,,CN,20140617,,CNY,647438.24,OUR,,,,,,,,SHANGHAI,CN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

    <br>

RDF,FTX,TEXT
<br>
</b>
<br>
</body></html>
```

below is my itext renderer code:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setTidyMark(false);
tidy.setDocType("omit");
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setInputEncoding("utf-8");
tidy.setOutputEncoding("utf-8");
//tidy.parse(new StringReader(documentJsoup.toString()), writer);
tidy.parse(new StringReader(inputFileString), writer);
writer.close();
String  pdfContent = writer.toString();

// Creating an instance of iText renderer which will be used to generate the pdf from the html document.
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();           

/*renderer.setDocument(doc, baseurl);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.flush();         

// close all the streams
//fis.close();
//os.close();
//instream.close();
 */
ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();

//renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
resolver.addFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(pdfContent);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
```

since i used font resolver and add font, chinese char are shown.... but pdf shows missing content.... last characters of that line (thats :"AI" from "shanghai" and next ",CN,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,") is not visible.... its seen something like:

[image: html2pdf: content missing]

i tried a lot to see whats wrong but couldnt find solution.
can anybody from u help me in resolving this issue pls ?? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Flying-saucer doesn't manage line wrapping in chinese text. It only insert line break on whitespaces. In your case, it means it cannot insert a line break after "nm,,,,", and it doesn't fit on the line.

It is a known bug in flying saucer (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=87)), but it's unlikely to be fixed soon.

The only workaround is to insert a whitespace anywhere in your string after the Chinese characters. It will make all the text visible.

Comment: this really helped me ! Hope they will fix the bug soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to add font type or font file in your application.

you can find code here [itextSharp - html to pdf some turkish characters are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397331/itextsharp-html-to-pdf-some-turkish-characters-are-missing)

this question is also same as your question..

if this helps you then please give points.

Comment: add FontFactory.Register(Path.Combine(_webHelper.MapPath("~/App_Data/Pdf/arial.ttf")),  "Garamond");   // just give a path of arial.ttf   add your chiness font file

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding below css rules into the body class and it worked perfectly.

`word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;`

"Adding whitespaces" works sometimes (I tried adding spaces after symbols like 。 or 、), but sometimes when there's no symbols it still overflows.