# How to generate a valid PDF/A file using iText and XMLWorker (HTML to PDF/A process)

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, pdfa, xmlworker

I'm currently developing a method that will accept HTML input and convert it into a valid PDF/A file. I know how to programmatically construct a valid PDF/A file using iText (reference: http://itextsupport.com/download/pdfa3.html) but I'm unable to generate a valid PDF/A file using HTML as input and using XMLWorker to transform this input into a PDF file. The problem that I have right now is due to the embedded fonts requirement of the PDF/A format. I always get this exception:

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica

I try to force which fonts will the HTML input use via a CSS file and I register the fonts I want to use in the output PDF file via the XMLWorkerFontProvider class, but it seems I'm doing something wrong because the exception commented above is always thrown.

What else do I need in order to XMLWorker uses the fonts registered via XMLWorkerFontProvider class? I want to avoid the use of the default font Helvetica in every HTML element present in the input.

Below is the code I'm using for testing:

style.css (just 1 line):

```
* { font: normal 100% Arial, sans-serif !important; }
```

Main.java:

```
package com.itextpdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ICC_Profile;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.CssFile;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliers;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersImpl;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        buf.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        buf.append("<html>");
        buf.append("<head>");
        buf.append("<title>Test</title>");
        buf.append("</head>");
        buf.append("<body>");
        buf.append("<p>This is a test</p>");
        buf.append("</body>");
        buf.append("</html>");

        OutputStream file = null;
        Document document = null;
        PdfAWriter writer = null;

        try {

            file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\amartin\\Desktop\\Test.pdf"));
            document = new Document();
            writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, file, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);

            // Create XMP metadata. It's a PDF/A requirement.
            writer.createXmpMetadata();

            document.open();

            // Set output intent. PDF/A requirement.
            ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/com/itextpdf/sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
            writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

            // CSS
            CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
            CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream("./css/style.css"));
            cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

            XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
            fontProvider.register("./fonts/arial.ttf");
            fontProvider.register("./fonts/sans-serif.ttf");
            fontProvider.addFontSubstitute("lowagie", "garamond");

            CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            // Pipelines
            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

            Reader reader = new StringReader(buf.toString());
            p.parse(reader);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (document != null && document.isOpen())
                document.close();

            try {

                if (file != null)
                    file.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {}

            if (writer != null && !writer.isCloseStream())
                writer.close();

        }

    }

}
```

edit:

Answering to Bruno, I have extended the FontFactoryImp class overriding the getFont() method (the one that has all the arguments). It calls the the System.out.println function like this:

```
System.out.println("=fontname: " + fontname + " =encoding: " + encoding + " =embedded : " + embedded + " =size: " + size + " =style: " + style + " =BaseColor: " + color)
```

and then calls parent.getFont() method with the same arguments. The only output I see is this:

> =fontname: null =encoding: Cp1252 =embedded : true =size: -1.0 =style: -1 =BaseColor: null
>   =fontname: null =encoding: Cp1252 =embedded : true =size: -1.0 =style: -1 =BaseColor: null

and the exception thrown, pasted before this code.

Comment: Create your own implementation of the `FontProvider` and write the fonts that are requested to the `System.out`. Make sure that all these fonts are mapped to a font program.

Comment: Hi, Bruno. I did what you commented and I have posted the results editing the question. If you'd like to give some feedback or advice I would be very grateful.

Comment: The output means that the font you defined in the CSS wasn't picked up by XML Worker. Now that I look at your CSS, I know why. Try `font-family: "Arial"` instead of using `font`.

Comment: Works like charm now, Bruno. Thank you VERY much for your help! Would you like to answer the question and then I can close it marking your answer as correct?

Again, thank you very much :-)

Comment: Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the feedback you're sending to the `System.out`, it seems that XML Worker doesn't pick up the font family you want to use.

Please specify the font family like this:

```
font-family: "Arial"
```

Using 'font' in CSS may work, but it's tricky. I think iText sees `normal` and interprets it as *Use the default font*.

Answer (score 3):

The complete code that makes this example work is the following:

style.css:

```
* {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.itextpdf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ICC_Profile;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.CssFile;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.css.StyleAttrCSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliers;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.CssAppliersImpl;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        String title = "Test";

        // Sample HTML content.
        buf.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        buf.append("<html>");
        buf.append("<head>");
        buf.append("<title>" + title + "</title>");
        buf.append("</head>");
        buf.append("<body>");
        buf.append("<p>This is a test</p>");
        buf.append("</body>");
        buf.append("</html>");

        OutputStream file = null;
        Document document = null;
        PdfAWriter writer = null;

        try {

            file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\amartin\\Desktop\\Test.pdf"));
            document = new Document();
            writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, file, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);

            // Avoid discrepances between document title and XMP metadata information.
            document.addTitle(title);

            // Create XMP metadata. It's a PDF/A requirement.
            writer.createXmpMetadata();

            document.open();

            // Set output intent. PDF/A requirement.
            ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/com/itextpdf/sRGB Color Space Profile.icm"));
            writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

            // CSS stylesheet.
            CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
            CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new FileInputStream("./css/style.css"));
            cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

            MyFontProvider fontProvider = new MyFontProvider();
            fontProvider.register("./fonts/arial.ttf");

            /* DEBUG
            System.out.println("Fonts present in " + fontProvider.getClass().getName());
            Set<String> registeredFonts = fontProvider.getRegisteredFonts();
            for (String font : registeredFonts)
                System.out.println(font);
            */

            CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            // Pipelines.
            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

            Reader reader = new StringReader(buf.toString());
            p.parse(reader);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (document != null && document.isOpen())
                document.close();

            try {

                if (file != null)
                    file.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {}

            if (writer != null && !writer.isCloseStream())
                writer.close();

        }

    }

}
```

MyFontProvider.java:

```
package com.itextpdf;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactoryImp;

public class MyFontProvider extends FontFactoryImp {

    @Override
    public Font getFont(String fontname, String encoding, boolean embedded,
            float size, int style, BaseColor color) {

        System.out.println("=fontname: " + fontname + " =encoding: " + encoding + " =embedded : " + embedded + " =size: " + size + " =style: " + style + " =BaseColor: " + color);

        return super.getFont(fontname, encoding, embedded, size, style, color);

    }

}
```

Again, thank you, Bruno. I'm really glad to get your help here :)

Comment: I used your code but get the error message `All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica`. How do I fix this on a Windows machine? I am using `fontProvider.register("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf");`