# Display Chinese Text in iTextSharp pdf from html c#

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, xmlworker

I want to display chinese text from html to pdf by using itextsharp in c#

Text in HTML is properly visible but when i tried to make pdf from Xml Parser in iTextSharp it does not show me chinese texts.

UTF8 encoding is not working properly. I also given Encoding.UTF8 but it also not worked.

Below are my code to generate PDF from html.

```
 public static byte[] HtmlToPDFConvert(string baseHtml, Rectangle pageSize)
 {
        Stream htmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(baseHtml ?? ""));

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(pageSize, 18f, 18f, 18f, 18f);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, htmlStream, null, Encoding.UTF8, FontFactory.FontImp);
            pdfDoc.Close();

            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();

            return bytes;
        }
 }
```

Comment: I've tried to convert an HTML to PDF by using pdfHTML (the successor of xmlParser), and it converted correctly. Can you provide with an example HTML you are trying to convert?

Comment: Check example html from the link : https://pastebin.com/FmVkbs2W

Comment: I am able to render those glyphs correctly, by using the FontProvider, and pointing to a directory with fonts that support them, like Noto CJK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xmlworker has been deprecated by [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfhtml), I've used it instead.

The only *trick* is to point to a font that supports the glyphs you want to use.

```
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
fontProvider.AddFont("fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf");
props.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(ORIG, FileMode.Open), doc, props);
```

Comment: if you are adamant to use the deprecated Xmlworker, take a look at the XMLWorkerFontProvider class for a probably similar solution.

Comment: i am using itext 5.5 how can use pdfhtml?

Comment: to use pdfHTML, you need to use iText 7.1. Do you have any strict requirements to use iText 5.5?

Comment: Yes as of now we have strict requirement of iText 5.5

Comment: then you cannot use pdfHTML. I'd advise to look into XMLWorkerFontProvider for iText 5.5 (XmlWorker) to solve the issue in a similar manner.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/25604008/1566339 for instance